# Playing a sound in on device with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I've looked at a lot of answers on here for this question and can't get any to work.

Here is my issue, I'm trying to play a sound on a button press, here is where the file is located[image: File Location]

Here is my code

```
- (void)playSoundWithOfThisFile:(NSString*)fileName {

NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:fileName,
                           [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                               error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = 1;

[player play];
```

}

When I run through the code the values are as follows

```
fileName = Mummy.mp3

`soundFilePath = Mummy.mp3`  (I've had it Sounds/Mummy.mp3 and this doesn't work either)
```

`soundFileURL  = Mummy.mp3` -- file:///

```
player = nil
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The error if I catch it is just a generic error with no info

Comment: What value are you passing in, as "fileName"?

Comment: Edited: filename = Mummy.mp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the below code

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                       pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge  CFURLRef)
                                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], & soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

Don't forget to import

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Comment: You should also declare `soundID`.

Comment: Yup you have to declare the soundID.Edited my answer.

Comment: This works, what are the advantages of this method as opposed to others, purely from interest (apart from the fact it works!)

Comment: AVAudioPlayer used for those sounds that require start and stop and volume control.While AudioToolbox is used to play short clips.

Comment: @Rajat can you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875385/why-sound-still-play-when-devices-silent-mode-is-on/70875992#70875992

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mummy" ofType:@"mp3"];  

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                               error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = 1;
[player play];
```

Docs on [pathForResource: ofType:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:)

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"how_to_play" ofType: @"mp3"];
            if(!self.theAudio)
            {
                self.theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
                self.theAudio.delegate = self;
                [self.theAudio play];
            }
```

put in viewcontroller.h

```
 < AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```